# Spinning progress indicator in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is possible to have spinning progress indicator control in windows phone 8 development?
Please provide us sample to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. We are trying to use native controls than third party controls.

Answer (score 4):

Spinner UIs aren't part of the native user experience for windows phone and would look weird and out of place on WP7/WP8. Considerusing an indeterminate progressbar at the top of the page to indicate a pending action.

The google term you're lookign for is SystemTray.ProgresIndicator. Example @ http://blog.duc.as/2011/10/08/using-the-system-tray-to-show-progress-in-windows-phone-7-mango/

```xml
<shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
    <shell:ProgressIndicator IsIndeterminate="true" IsVisible="True" Text="Click me..." />
</shell:SystemTray.ProgressIndicator>
```

```cs
ProgressIndicator progress = new ProgressIndicator
{
    IsVisible = true,
    IsIndeterminate = true,
    Text = "Downloading details..."
};
SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, progress);
```

Comment: We got the design as we expected. Please check this url for your references .http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/creating-spinning-progress-animation-in-windows-phone-8

Comment: Code to easily recreate W8 prog ring on WP8 here:
http://briandunnington.github.io/progressring-wp8.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's the documentation and example to build a custom indeterminate progress bar on your own. The example is still with rectangles, but can be adapted to whatever you want:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442303%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: We got the design as we expected. Please check this url for your references .http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/creating-spinning-progress-animation-in-windows-phone-8